# Android Studio Gradle build still very slow after make all suggestions from other threads

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I know there's a lot of questions about that, but I have already tried all I found without success.

I have changed settings like this:
[image]

I have set gradle to work offline.

I have add a file gradle.properties to /Users/[my user]/.gradle with this content:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Settings specified in this file will override any Gradle settings
# configured through the IDE.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# The Gradle daemon aims to improve the startup and execution time of Gradle.
# When set to true the Gradle daemon is to run the build.
# TODO: disable daemon on CI, since builds should be clean and reliable on servers
org.gradle.daemon=true

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Enables new incubating mode that makes Gradle selective when configuring projects.
# Only relevant projects are configured which results in faster builds for large multi-projects.
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

After all, still if I change one line in my code and I press the button to debug it takes 1 minute and 30 seconds building and then it starts debugging on device. I remember 1 or 2 years ago I used to use Eclipse with ADT and when pressing the button to debug on device it was almost instantaneous.

I have a Macbook Pro 2.5GHz Intel i5, 8GB DDR3 and SSD 256.

Is there anything else to do to improve Gradle build?

Comment: Does anyone can help me on this please?

Comment: My problem was solved in new Android Studio version with Instant Run.

Comment: I also use the newest version of AS with the instant run and I noticed a strange thing. When I test the app with the official android virtual device it takes hell lot of time to compile the code but also the installation of .apk file takes a lot of time. With genymotion, however, it's way faster.